# Поиск по txt файлу в С#

Tags: c#, массивы, парсер

Всем добрый вечер.
Встала следующая задача.
Имеется множество файлов с практически однотипным содержанием следующего типа:

```
Velocity[i] (m/s),"X (m)","Y (m)","Z (m)"
6.937014e-01,8.000000e-02,1.800000e-02,2.500000e-02
3.624529e-01,8.000000e-02,1.900000e-02,2.500000e-02
3.628664e-01,8.000000e-02,1.900000e-02,2.200000e-02
3.632514e-01,8.000000e-02,1.900000e-02,1.900000e-02
```

Как видно он состоит из четырех столбцов. Мне необходимо создать dataGridView в котором будут хранится эти значения по столбцам, которые как видно разделяются запятой, далее необходимо провести поиск по совпадения по трем столбцам и получить значение четвертого столбца и при этом номер столбца где произошло совпадение. Как ни делаю что то не получается!
Буду рад любой помощи! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Прочитать файл? Извлечь из прочитанного файла данные? Создать `DataGridView`? Загрузить данные в `DataGridView`? Получить из UI образец для поиска? Пробежаться по загруженным данным и найти совпадения? Вывести найденный индекс? У вас тут куча задач.

Comment: Так открываю файл.
StreamReader fp = new StreamReader("D:\\Re_1293_steady_meshA_membrane_u1_table_time_1.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            string str = fp.ReadToEnd();
Короче думаю код не правильный! В C# я новичок, поэтому может подскажите ссылочки и материалы для ликбеза! Код у меня безобразный смысла даже нет его показывать!
Для парсинга использую регулярные выражения Regex

Comment: Может есть статьи или книжки где рассматриваются данные задачи?

Comment: Читать CSV можно читать через .NET класс: http://it-proposition.blogspot.ru/2012/12/cvs-reader-from-net-framework.html
Но ты можешь рассматривать сваи файлы как базу данных и подключаться к ним по ODBC: http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Comment: Хм, странно, комментарий куда-то пропал.

Файл читается как-то так:

    File.ReadLines(path).Select(l => l.Split(",").ToList());

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<string> Source = new List<string>();
string FileName="1.txt"
Source.Clear();
Source.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
//source[0]   -1 строка
string[] MasNums = source[0].Split(',');
//MasNums[0] -1 число в 1 строке 

//перевод его в плавающее число если разделитель ,
double res = double.Parse(mas_text[0], new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Сравнения тут нехитрое пробежаться циклом по массиву и сравнить ифами.
Добавления в дата грид тоже вещь не сложная)